# Need to make a USB device look like a keyboard

Tags: usb, badusb

My company is implementing "BitLocker to Go" encryption to encrypt USB flash drives.

However we us Barco USB wireless presentation devices. Each time one is plugged in, Bitlocker wants to encrypt it (it won't because it is to small to encrypt) but there is this popup dance we go through and it confuses people. I would love to have the Barco device show up as a keyboard a (human interface device) problem would be solved!

Can this be done? I know it can! like a "Rubber Duck" without the Bad USB motive behind it.

Comment: That might break the functionality as the software (ClickShare?) might be looking for a specific device class. But assuming it doesn't, I suggest watching the original talk by Karsten Nohl. BadUSB also covered the "Rubber Ducky" attack, but it was mainly about what you're asking; reprogramming devices instead of using dedicated hardware. For that you need proprietary (secret) SCSI commands to send over the USB to flash a modified firmware. That  command can be sniffed with wireshark if there's a firmware update utility for the USB controller.

Comment: Maybe a USB drive that automatically encrypts data would be better than going through all that.

Comment: You can disable the popups from BitLocker in Settings "Notifications and Actions". [Source](https://penteract.net/site/Site1/Blogs/High-Tech/Windows/BitLocker/prevent-popup.aspx) (But why is there a popup? I don't get a popup every time I connect a flash drive that isn't encrypted.)